The permission issue that occurs when software uses AFS files to have storage space
This might be a somewhat specific issue. I'm currently in the process of installing nvr software. I've configured the server to generate storage space (as AFS format files), but it seems impossible due to permission problems. Is there a way to resolve this?
An error occurred while saving configuration changes. 
Details: Failed to create archive volume. Check the required permissions and the allowed file size in file system.

The reason I'm reaching out to Ubuntu is because I've successfully completed the same process on Windows. Thanks for reading.

Silly question, but are you running Ubuntu or a different OS? If it’s Ubuntu, the OpenAFS project page has some documentation that may answer the questions you have.
